# How to set up and use FindBugs after installation?

Tags: windows

Good day, am a masters student who is currently working on my thesis
which involves using formal method to prove the correctness of my
application. The application is about traffic light control system and
 i wrote it in java, it has a simulator that does the control. Now i
have choosing FindBugs as the tool to proof the correctness of my
Simulation system, but am having difficulty doing the set up of
FindBugs after installation. Please can you help me out with some
guide line. Am using a windows vista OS even though i have read
through the tutorial and manual i still can set it up. please help or
do i need any specification language?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any IDE?(eclipse/IntellijA)
I suggest you to use eclipse since it is free.
After installing eclipse, import you project to workspace and install the 'findbu'g plugin for eclipse. When you rightclick on your project you will see findbug option..Just 'run' that will show the bugs in your code.